# NSString @"\" adding backslash character objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Does anyone know of an easy way to add a single backslash (`\`) to a `NSString` in Objective-C? I am trying to have a `NSString *temp = @"\/Date(100034234)\/"`;

I am able to get a double backslash or no backslash, but unable to get a single backslash. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

The string `@"\\"` is a single backslash, `@"\\\\"` is a double backslash

Comment: Are you sure about it? When I print the NSString using NSLog it shows up as a double backslash.

Comment: Using NSLog(string) is bad practice; all someone has to do to crash your system is pass in e.g. %d, and it'll be interpreted as a dereference for a value. If you want to print out the value of an NSString on its own, then you should use:

NSLog(@"@%",string)

since then no values in the 'string' will affect the resulting output, which is an object type.

Answer (score 8):

The strings and NSLog are working fine for me (iPhone SDK 3.1.2 and Xcode 3.2.1):

```
NSLog(@"\\"); // output is one backslash
NSLog(@"\\\\"); // output is two backslashes
NSLog(@"\\/Date(100034234)\\/"); // output is \/Date(100034234)\/
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116669/add-backslash-to-string-in-objective-c/2116731#2116731).

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in NSLog. I found a mailing list archive with a message dated in 2002 of someone that filed a bug for this [here](http://www.omnigroup.com/mailman/archive/macosx-dev/2002-February/035425.html). The person also said this:

> Nothing has been done as far as I can tell.  I don't understand how 
>   they've done it, but the escaping does work for the string, just not for 
>   NSLog.

So I guess you will have to come up with your own implementation of a log message if you really want backslashes.

Comment: Is there any other way to be sure of this? Also, do you know any other way to represent a single literal backslash character and append it to a string?

Comment: Can you do something like `NSString *string = @"\\"; NSLog(@"%@", string);`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with NSLog. It is his string that contains four backslashes, probably placed there by some code that replaces one backslash with two. When he prints them it looks like 2, because there are four.

Answer (score 3):

This code *does* give the requested output:

```
NSString *temp = @"\\/Date(100034234)\\/";
NSLog(@"%@",temp);
```

However I had an issue with my JSON toolkit (SBJSON) that replaced all occurrances of "\\" with "\\\\", which did cause issues as described in the other answers and the comments.

The result was a string looking like:

```
@"\\\\/Date(100034234)\\\\/"
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116669/add-backslash-to-string-in-objective-c/11762667#11762667)

The solution was using:

```
temp = [temp stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"];
```

Comment: So far I still expect everything to work just fine. I have yet to see a non-working example that's not buggy itself.

Comment: Ben - For predefined Strings, they should be (it would make sense). But in many cases when these questions occur, they are not intended to be used only for predefined Strings. This was a long time ago so my memories are vague, but I guess that in my case, running data strings unknown at compile time through JSON messed up the results.

Answer (score 1):

Where you want a \  add or remove. just \\ on that place.