# Unicode not working properly in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, unicode

My unicode is `\u20AC` when I set it on `UILabel` but I'm getting unicode on label. Some time it is printing euro but mostly it is printing unicode on label.

My code is over here

```
    NSLog(@"Currecy %@",currencySymbol);
    UILabel *priceLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 10, 45, 25)];

    priceLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    priceLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    priceLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Bold" size:15];
    priceLbl.tag  = 1001;
    fair = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",arc4random()%50];
    priceLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",fair,currencySymbol];
```

**Output** 
Currecy \u20AC

```
Printing description of priceLbl:
<UILabel: 0x7faade3095a0; frame = (185 10; 50 25); text = '\u20AC'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1001; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7faadbd91bb0>>
```

[image]

And I'm trying to set at my end getting output as I would like. for example

[image]

Getting server response

```
{
    currency = "\\u20AC";
    description = "You have been successfully logged in.";
}

and the currency symbol replacing "\\" with "\"

NSString *currency = [response[@"currency"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"];
```

Comment: @hasan83 Please see my updated code.

Comment: @halfer Yes, it is useful

Comment: your code looks fine. can you add the declaration of currencySymbol and how you assign the value for it. or the nsarray you have the currencies there?

Comment: try priceLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \u20ac",fair,currencySymbol]; as a test

Comment: @hasan83 The currency symbol coming from server side. When i'm trying to set at my end same unicode getting euro symbol but when it is coming from server side its printing unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NGUYEN MINH answer worked for me as follow:

```
NSString *currencySymbol = @"\\u20AC";
NSString *fair = @"1.99 ";

NSString *convertedString = currencySymbol;

CFStringRef transform = CFSTR("Any-Hex/Java");
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)convertedString, NULL, transform, YES);

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", fair, convertedString];
```

The problem is that your currencySymbol contains: `@"\\u20AC"` which is a string of 6 characters not the one character string `@"\u20AC"`

**Another working solution:**

```
NSString *currencySymbol = @"\\u20AC";
NSString *fair = @"1.99 ";

currencySymbol = [NSString
                   stringWithCString:[currencySymbol cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                   encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];


label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", fair, currencySymbol];
```

Comment: No, please see updated answer. When i'm trying to set this unicode at my end then getting output as i wanna & working perfect but the currency symbol  coming from server and the currency symbol are same but printing unicode.

Comment: I know that. when its come from the server it comes as a string @"\\u20AC"

Comment: No, i replaced it with @"\" symbol. And please see my updated question.

Comment: That won't work you don't have \\\\ = \\ in your string you have \\ = \. I tried that won't work that way. but NGUYEN MINH solution worked.

Comment: you need to replace \\ with \. but the compiler will refuse it. compilation error.

Comment: Please have a look for backslash in ios. We are using \\\\ for \\ . for ex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281141/nsstring-adding-backslash-character-objective-c

Comment: thats in consideration. when placing a \ in a string it should be \\. but when you want it to be part of unicode you put one \. single \ is not a backslash character when its added to unicode. the hall thing is a character.

Comment: When i'm trying to put @"\" getting compiler error "Unexpected @ in program."

Comment: Your last solution working proper thanks a lot dude.

Answer (score 1):

please try:

```
NSString *convertedString = @"some text"; //Your unicode string here
CFStringRef transform = CFSTR("Any-Hex/Java");
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)convertedString, NULL, transform, YES);
yourLabel.text = convertedString;
```

Comment: When i'm trying to set your code, the application getting crashed & giving bad access.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the output of NSLog with the real data.

\u20ac is how NSLog displays a Euro symbol, because the Euro symbol is the Unicode character u20ac.

Comment: Please see my attached image i show you on image. its also printing unicode on label. So please see the attached image.